# I need help in inno setup custom page

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup I have created a custom page with following code which has 3 text boxes.

Now I want to validate that text box on custom form next button click. If in text.text='2121212' something text is entered by user then only next button enabled.

```
[CustomMessages]
CustomForm_Caption=CustomForm Caption
CustomForm_Description=CustomForm Description
CustomForm_Label1_Caption0=College Name:
CustomForm_Label2_Caption0=Product Type:
CustomForm_Label3_Caption0=Product ID:

[Code]
var
  Label1: TLabel;
  Label2: TLabel;
  Label3: TLabel;
  Edit1: TEdit;
  Edit2: TEdit;
  Edit3: TEdit;
  Edit4: TEdit;
  Edit5: TEdit;
  Edit6: TEdit;

{ CustomForm_Activate }

procedure CustomForm_Activate(Page: TWizardPage);
begin
  // enter code here...


end;

{ CustomForm_ShouldSkipPage }

function CustomForm_ShouldSkipPage(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

{ CustomForm_BackButtonClick }

function CustomForm_BackButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

{ CustomForm_NextkButtonClick }

function CustomForm_NextButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\SGS2.2\CS',
    'College Name', Edit1.Text);
   RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\SGS2.2\CS',
    'Product Type', Edit2.Text);
    RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\SGS2.2\CS',
    'Product ID', Edit3.Text);
  Result := True;
   end;

{ CustomForm_CancelButtonClick }

procedure CustomForm_CancelButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  // enter code here...
end;

{ CustomForm_CreatePage }

function CustomForm_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(
    PreviousPageId,
    ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Caption}'),
    ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Description}')
  );

{ Label1 }
  Label1 := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with Label1 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Label1_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(16);
    Top := ScaleY(24);
    Width := ScaleX(70);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;

  { Label2 }
  Label2 := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with Label2 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Label2_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(17);
    Top := ScaleY(56);
    Width := ScaleX(70);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;

  { Label3 }
  Label3 := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with Label3 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Label3_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(17);
    Top := ScaleY(88);
    Width := ScaleX(70);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;

  { Edit1 }
  Edit1 := TEdit.Create(Page);
  with Edit1 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(115);
    Top := ScaleY(24);
    Width := ScaleX(273);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    TabOrder := 0;
  end;

  { Edit2 }
  Edit2 := TEdit.Create(Page);
  with Edit2 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(115);
    Top := ScaleY(56);
    Width := ScaleX(273);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    TabOrder := 1;
  end;

  { Edit3 }
  Edit3 := TEdit.Create(Page);
  with Edit3 do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(115);
    Top := ScaleY(88);
    Width := ScaleX(273);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    TabOrder := 2;
  end;

  with Page do
  begin
    OnActivate := @CustomForm_Activate;
    OnShouldSkipPage := @CustomForm_ShouldSkipPage;
    OnBackButtonClick := @CustomForm_BackButtonClick;
    OnNextButtonClick := @CustomForm_NextButtonClick;
    OnCancelButtonClick := @CustomForm_CancelButtonClick;
  end;

  Result := Page.ID;
end;

{ CustomForm_InitializeWizard }

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin

  CustomForm_CreatePage(wpWelcome);

end;
```

Answer (score 10):

This should get you started:

```
    ; -- CodeDlg.iss --
    ;
    ; This script shows how to insert custom wizard pages into Setup and how to handle
    ; these pages. Furthermore it shows how to 'communicate' between the [Code] section
    ; and the regular Inno Setup sections using {code:...} constants. Finally it shows
    ; how to customize the settings text on the 'Ready To Install' page.

    [Setup]
    AppName=My Program
    AppVerName=My Program version 1.5
    DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
    DisableProgramGroupPage = yes
    UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
    OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

    [Files]
    Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

    [CustomMessages]
    CustomForm_Caption=CustomForm Caption
    CustomForm_Description=CustomForm Description
    CustomForm_Label1_Caption0=College Name:
    CustomForm_Label2_Caption0=Product Type:
    CustomForm_Label3_Caption0=Product ID:

    [Code]
    Var
    Page: TWizardPage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Edit6: TEdit;

    procedure  EdtOnChange (Sender: TObject);
    Var
    MyEdit : TEdit;
    begin
    MyEdit := TEdit(Sender);
    if MyEdit.Text = '2121212' then
      WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := true
    Else
      WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := false;
    end;


    procedure InitializeWizard;
    Var
      CheckBox: TCheckBox;
    begin
      Page := CreateCustomPage( wpWelcome, ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Caption}'), ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Description}') );


    { Label1 } Label1 := TLabel.Create(Page); with Label1 do begin Parent := Page.Surface; Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Label1_Caption0}'); Left := ScaleX(16); Top := ScaleY(24); Width := ScaleX(70); Height := ScaleY(13); end;

    { Label2 } Label2 := TLabel.Create(Page); with Label2 do begin Parent := Page.Surface; Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Label2_Caption0}'); Left := ScaleX(17); Top := ScaleY(56); Width := ScaleX(70); Height := ScaleY(13); end;

    { Label3 } Label3 := TLabel.Create(Page); with Label3 do begin Parent := Page.Surface; Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Label3_Caption0}'); Left := ScaleX(17); Top := ScaleY(88); Width := ScaleX(70); Height := ScaleY(13); end;

    { Edit1 } Edit1 := TEdit.Create(Page); with Edit1 do begin Parent := Page.Surface; Left := ScaleX(115); Top := ScaleY(24); Width := ScaleX(273); Height := ScaleY(21); TabOrder := 0; end;

    { Edit2 } Edit2 := TEdit.Create(Page); with Edit2 do begin Parent := Page.Surface; Left := ScaleX(115); Top := ScaleY(56); Width := ScaleX(273); Height := ScaleY(21); TabOrder := 1; end;

    { Edit3 } Edit3 := TEdit.Create(Page); with Edit3 do begin Parent := Page.Surface; Left := ScaleX(115); Top := ScaleY(88); Width := ScaleX(273); Height := ScaleY(21); TabOrder := 2; end;

      Edit3.OnChange := @EdtOnChange;

    end;

    procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
    begin
    If CurPageID = Page.ID Then
      WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := false;
    end;

    end.
```

As it's written, it checks the third text box for the '2121212' value.  If you'd like it on the first or second box, you'd want to add an OnChange event handler for the appropriate edit box.